# cordova-plugin-smooch issues with iOS/Android app built using creator.ionic.io

Tags: ionic-framework, smooch

Am using http://creator.ionic.io to create a hybrid iOS/Android app.

Have added cordova-plugin-smooch as a plugin in Code Settings.

Have added ionic-native.min.js.

Have added smoochio.js with following code...

> ```
> Smooch.init({
>     "appToken": "MY-TOKEN", 
>     "soundNotificationEnabled": "true", 
>     "imageUploadEnabled": "true",
> });
> ```

The smooch.io button appears in the app but I think it's not 'native' because when user tries to type in message field, the iOS keyboard goes on top of the message input field so user can't see what they are typing.  Also, in the smooch.io message window header, the 'X' or close icon doesn't show up...

Not sure what I'm missing to activate the 'native' plugin so it functions correctly on the phone.  Thanks for any help.